# Sending POST request to ESB

Tags: wso2, google-custom-search, apache-synapse, wso2-esb

I'm trying to create a Google Custom Search connector for [WSO2 ESB](http://wso2.com/products/enterprise-service-bus/). After creating the connector I have added the connector to ESB. Then I want to test it.

My test init file like this:

```
<template name="listVolume" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <parameter name="apiKey" description="Full-text search query string." />
    <parameter name="csiKey" description="Full-text search query string." />
    <parameter name="searchPara" description="Full-text search query string." />
    <sequence>
    <property name="uri.var.apiKey" expression="$func:apiKey" />
    <property name="uri.var.csiKey" expression="$func:csiKey" />
    <property name="uri.var.searchPara" expression="$func:searchPara" />
    <call>
        <endpoint>
            <http method="get"
                  uri-template="https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key={uri.var.apiKey}&amp;cx={uri.var.csiKey}&amp;q={uri.var.searchPara}" />
        </endpoint>
    </call>
    </sequence>
</template>
```

After I have configured a custom proxy service within the ESB like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
       name="googlecustomsearch_list"
       transports="https,http"
       statistics="disable"
       trace="disable"
       startOnLoad="true">
   <target>
      <inSequence>
     <property name="apiKey" expression="json-eval($.apiKey)"/>
     <property name="csiKey" expression="json-eval($.csiKey)"/>
     <property name="searchPara" expression="json-eval($.searchPara)"/>
     <googleCustomSearch.listSearch>
        <apiKey>{$ctx:apiKey}</apiKey>
        <csiKey>{$ctx:csiKey}</csiKey>
        <searchPara>{$ctx:searchPara}</searchPara>
     </googleCustomSearch.listSearch>
     <respond/>
      </inSequence>
      <outSequence>
     <log/>
     <send/>
      </outSequence>
   </target>
   <description/>
</proxy>
```

Then I test it in a REST client like this:

```
POST http://nilash-TECRA-M11:8280/services/googlecustomsearch_list

{
"apiKey":"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
 "csiKey":"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
 "searchPara":"google"
}
```

Then I get the output like this:

```
Status Code: 202 Accepted
Connection: keep-alive
Date: Sat, 14 Jun 2014 05:22:34 GMT
Server: WSO2-PassThrough-HTTP
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
```

But the searched results will not appears.I got below listed this error in console.

```
ERROR - SynapseJsonPath #stringValueOf. Error evaluating JSON Path <$.apiKey>. Returning  empty result. Error>>> invalid path
[2014-06-14 10:52:34,883] ERROR - SynapseJsonPath #stringValueOf. Error evaluating JSON  Path <$.csiKey>. Returning empty result. Error>>> invalid path
[2014-06-14 10:52:34,884] ERROR - SynapseJsonPath #stringValueOf. Error evaluating JSON Path <$.searchPara>. Returning empty result. Error>>> invalid path
```

But if I put Google API keys directly in my configuration in init file like this I can get expected results.

```
 <http method="get" uri-template="https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?q={uri.var.searchQuery}&amp;key=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&amp;cx=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"/>
```

What can be the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

seems you have an error on JSON Path, change

```
  <googleCustomSearch.listSearch>
```

to

```
 <googleCustomSearch.listVolume>
```

and try. Use below listed blog to get more information.

http://chanakaindrajith.blogspot.com/2014/04/getting-started-with-wso2-esb-connectors.html

Comment: Even I have change the path, I have got the following error message: {
  error: {
    errors: [1]
       0:  {
           domain: "usageLimits"
           reason: "keyInvalid"
           message: "Bad Request"
           }

     code: 400
     message: "Bad Request"
     }
}

Comment: so its include your error..keyInvalid.. try with some other app account credentials https://developers.google.com/custom-search/json-api/v1/using_rest

Answer (score 0):

The JSON request is invalid. you have missed the ','

```html
{
"apiKey":"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
 "csiKey":"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
 "searchPara":"google"
}
```